# How to clear two setIntervals assigned to same variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, ecmascript-5

As far as I know we can clearInterval as:

```js
var go = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("go");
}, 5000);

clearInterval(go);
```

But for some reason in my javascript code I have same variable being assigned two time the setInterval. Now even if I clear it multiple times it doesn't get cleared. Example:

```js
var go = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("go");
}, 1000);

var go = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("go");
}, 1000);

clearInterval(go);
clearInterval(go);

clearInterval(go);
clearInterval(go);
```

My questions is:

What is going on here? How does javascript deal with this situation? What's wrong with `go`? Why doesn't it get cleared?

Comment: You cannot. You've overwritten the previous timer id. It's lost.

Comment: its not like if you clear it once it'll point back to your first one

Comment: relevant: `const` would prevent you from reassigning the `intervalId`

Comment: This is a good question why does it have so many downvotes? Is stackoverflow resistant and hateful towards beginner questions?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You've overwritten the previous timer id. It's lost.

Only the second interval, with the id that is currently stored in the variable, will get cleared, regardless how often you call `clearInterval`.

You will need multiple variables (or a datastructure of timers, e.g. an array):

```
var go1 = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("go 1");
}, 1000);

var go2 = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("go 2");
}, 1000);

clearInterval(go1);
clearInterval(go1); // nothing will happen
clearInterval(go2);
```

Comment: Thanx for your response. Where does javascript store previous instance of `go`? Does javascript engine assign two spaces in stack to `go`?

Comment: There is no "previous instance". There is only one space, and when the variable gets written to the previous value is not stored anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some of the comments, what you've done here is reassign your `go` variable. Each call to `setInterval` returns a different id. Once you've reassigned the only variable referencing that value, the previous value is lost.

When it comes to unique identifiers, it's batter to keep an expandable list of them so that you won't lose the identifier for the process. I suggest making an array and pushing each new id to it (using it much like a stack), that way they are all in one place but are still able to be individually referenced:

```
var intervalIDs = []; //we would want something like this to be a global variable
//adding IDs to the array:
intervalIDs.push(window.setInterval(function(){console.log("go 1");}, 1000));
intervalIDs.push(window.setInterval(function(){console.log("go 2");}, 1000));
//now we know we can find both IDs in the future
//clearing an interval:
window.clearInterval(intervalIDs.pop()); //takes the last ID out of the array and uses it to stop that interval. this could be done in a for loop to clear every one you've set using the above method.
//OR if you happen to know the index (in the array) of a specific interval id you want to clear:
var index = /*index number*/;
window.clearInterval(intervalIDs.splice(index, 1)[0]);
```

The point is to ensure that you maintain the means of referencing your intervals (or anything else that acts similarly, for that matter).